# How run C# code in sequence and show some data in view while still program is running

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a query that I am running in the mvc5. I need to write the start time on screen, then write something like loading… then write the time that is finished running. I am not sure what to use to write this in sequence not all at once, This is my code now that is writing all at once when finished running.

```
   public IActionResult GetQuery()
    {
        ViewData["Timefrom"] = DateTime.Now;
        
        var Query= _context.Order.FromSqlRaw("EXECUTE [dbo].[GetStatusReport].ToList();
        
        ViewData["Timefrom2"] = DateTime.Now;
        
        return View(Query);
    }
```

and this is my view:

```
 @model IEnumerable<Order>
 @{
   ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
 }


<tbody>
Start Time: @ViewData["Timefrom"]   //need this showup 1st before query running 
@foreach (var item in Model)        //show loading when here  
{
    <tr>
        <td width="30%">@item.OrderId</td>
        <td width="30%">@item.Name</td>
        <td width="30%">@item.Location</td>
    </tr>
}  
End Time: @ViewData["Timefrom2"]    //show this at end when done running query
```

Comment: If you need to update page state, fetch data from the server, and update page state again all without reloading the page then the technology you're looking for is "AJAX".

Comment: Ajax would be a bad choice because he had mentioned it is a longer running process. Which means he will have to do DB query for ajax call to figure out how much have been processed. Each ajax call will put a load and delay the process further.

Answer (score 0):

Your case is a perfect candidate for a technology called WebSocket. In Asp.net MVC you can use SignalR library to implement WebSockets with very few lines of code.

> **Update 15/10/2021**: You can follow the example on this answer to know about WebSocket technology and how you can integrate it to your
> existing Asp.net application.

For example here is how your page will work:

- Page loads from Controller Action. When the page loads you start the heavy process
- After the page loads it connects to a specific end point (using WebSocket) on the server. Using WebSocket connection the server and page will be able send/receive data as required - Bi-directional! In this case server will send updates to the page when required. Page will receive the data. And do not have to pull data with Ajax in intervals.
- In the bulk process (that you had started when the page was loading) you process data and send an regular update to the WebSocket
- Any client connected to the socket will get the data (in this case your page is one client). You can consume the same data from nay different pages.

Here is a diagram how the SignalR based WebSocket works (The image is collected from [here](https://www.pubnub.com/blog/what-are-websockets/) where you get the detail explanation):

[image]

**Here is a sample Hub:**

```
using AutoMapper;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.SignalR;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Hubs
{
    public class ProcessHub : Hub
    {
        private static IHubContext<ProcessHub> _hubContext;
        public static Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> AppClientStorage = new Dictionary<int, List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>>();

        public ProcessHub(IMapper mapper, IHubContext<ProcessHub> hubContext)
        {
            _hubContext = hubContext;
        }

        public async Task<string> RegisterToSocket(int userId)
        {
            KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair = new KeyValuePair<string, string>(subscriptionTypeName, Context.ConnectionId);

            AddToDictionary(userId, keyValuePair);

            return "Successfully Registered.";
        }

        public static async Task NotifyUpdatesRingAsync(int userId)
        {
            if (AppClientStorage.ContainsKey(userId))
            {
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> userSubscriptions = AppClientStorage[userId];

                if (userSubscriptions != null)
                {
                    List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> subscribers = userSubscriptions.ToList();

                    foreach (var subsc in subscribers)
                    {
                        string data = "10% Processed. Please wait..."
                        await _hubContext.Clients.Client(subsc.Value).SendAsync("ReceiveProcessData", data);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        private void AddToDictionary(int userId, KeyValuePair<string, string> keyValuePair)
        {
            if (!AppClientStorage.ContainsKey(userId))
            {
                AppClientStorage.Add(userId, new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>() { keyValuePair });
            }
            else
            {
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> subscriptions = AppClientStorage[userId];
                List<KeyValuePair<string, string>> connectionList = subscriptions.Where(s => s.Key.Equals(keyValuePair.Key)).ToList();

                if (!connectionList.Any(s => s.Value.Equals(keyValuePair.Value)))
                {
                    subscriptions.Add(keyValuePair);
                    AppClientStorage[userId] = subscriptions;
                }
            }
        }
        
        public override Task OnDisconnectedAsync(Exception exception)
        {
            string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;
            return base.OnDisconnectedAsync(exception);
        }       
    }
}
```

**Then in the CShtml** - Code to connect to the Hub when page loads:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
        .withUrl("/processhub")
        .withAutomaticReconnect()
        .build();

    connection.on("ReceiveProcessData", function (data) {
        // Data sent by the server from the NotifyUpdatesProcessAsync function will arrive here
        // Display the 'Data' on the page as needed
    });

    connection.start();

    function subscribe() {
        connection.invoke("RegisterToSocket", 123).then(function (data) {
            // 123 is ur user Id            
            //Display the data as needed
        }).catch(err => console.error(err.toString()));
    }

</script>
```

In the Action/Service where you are processing the data, just call the hub method to push the data to the client like this:

```
await ProcessHub.NotifyUpdatesProcessAsync(123);
```

Here 123 is the User Id who will get the data.

If you do not know how to configure a hub and hook it up in startup you can follow any tutorial on the web. For example [here is one](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/78d182/signalr-sample-chat-application-in-C-Sharp/).

Comment: Be careful about using other people's images without attribution. The image used appears to come from https://www.pubnub.com/blog/what-are-websockets/ and does not appear to be licensed for reuse. Indeed, they have a copyright on their site: © 2010 - 2021 PubNub Inc. All Rights Reserved.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thanks for pointing it out. I have updated the answer

Comment: Also, while it may be true the user could use web sockets (and SignalR specifically) to solve this problem, this answer does not show them how to do that; it gives them a generic overview of how the technology works, but no code specific to the question. It would be a great answer to "How can I update a page from the server-side without doing a full postback in ASP.NET MVC" with no specifics, but this does have specifics.

Comment: @HereticMonkey  What do you mean by 'no code specific to the question'? There are sample codes that anyone can copy from here and use in their applications.

Comment: Well, how is `AddToDictionary` relevant to the OP's `GetQuery` function? How does the output of `NotifyUpdatesProcessAsync` relate to the view the OP shows in their code?

Comment: @HereticMonkey the  `AddToDictionary` is used in the `RegisterToSocket` function to manage the users connections where data would be pushed by the web socket. In my sample code I have provided a solution for the connection management too which he will need down the track. Which is very relevant I think. Also the `NotifyUpdatesProcessAsync` has an output which is what the questioner had asked for - display some progress. He can implement his business logic there. Nothing to do in `GetQuery` function because he has executing a SQL process in there.

Comment: *Nothing to do in `GetQuery` function* That's what I mean by 'no code specific to the question'. You can copy and paste this answer on any question that could conceivably use sockets. It's more an advertisement for sockets than a specific answer to this question.

Comment: @HereticMonkey He needs to hook the web socket in a different section of the application where he will be sending the status update that is being processed in the `GetQuery` function. Which he has started when the page is loading.

Comment: Don't tell me, I already know how. [Edit] your answer to tell the OP (and others who get here from search) how to use web sockets to realize their idea.

Comment: @HereticMonkey cold down! I have added comment so that anyone can read the answer and realize their idea!